# DropDownListFor enum expression, selected item not selecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, dropdownlistfor

I have done lots of research and found that some times the name of the object can cause issues and so on. However I have (at least I think) determined that this is not an issue. Most of the issues I see people have is trying to convert enum to the dropdownlist, which I do not need.

I am using:

```
public enum PriorityTypeEnum
{
    Low = 1,
    Medium = 2,
    High = 3,
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentTicket.Priority, Model.PriorityList.SetSelectedItem((int)Model.CurrentTicket.Priority))
```

Which gets the list of all the Priorities, and sets the selected item to the CurrenTicket.Priority.

Now, the list itself that is returned is fine. The item that should be selected is, however nothing is selected in the DropDownListFor. After doing debugging if I change the type of the Priority from the enum (PriorityTypeEnum) to an int, it selects the right one. As you can tell, this is really annoying when I have an enum that holds the values.

My question is how to make it select properly and still use the enum?

I don't know if I am missing something very simple here. I have been looking at this way to long.

Comment: Have you tried `EnumDropDownListFor`?

Comment: Using @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentTicket.Priority, Model.PriorityList.SetSelectedItem((int)Model.CurrentTicket.Priority)) does not work. The list still has the correct selected item, but doesn't get selected on the page. (other lists that doesn't use an enum still work).

Comment: What's the purpose of `Model.PriorityList.SetSelectedItem((int)Model.CurrentTicket.Priority)`? Just set your enum value to whatever you want as a default in the controller. This just clutters your view.

Comment: PriorityList returns a List<SelectListItem> and the .SetSelectedItem just sets the item in the list Selected = true.

Comment: There's no need for a select list with `EnumDropDownListFor`. The values that go into the list are calculated from the helper through the enum type you pass to it.

Comment: Apparently I had an older version of MVC for some odd stupid reason. After updating it looks like it works, and everything works nicely with the EnumDropDownListFor. Thanks a ton! Looks like it was a simpler answer than what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the value of the `SelectListItem` to `Model.CurrentTicket.Priority.ToString()` rather than converting to an `int`?

You new select list would be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CurrentTicket.Priority, Model.PriorityList.Select(enum =>
{
    Text = enum.ToString(),
    Value = enum.ToString()   
})
```

Then in the controller you can set the `model.CurrentTicket.Priority` property to the the desired value to be selected